# applying functor on print

Tags: haskell, functor

I've been trying to print 2 values separately, and I tried this code:

```hs
import System.Directory
main = getCurrentDirectory >>= \x -> (print <$> doesFileExist x) >> (print <$> doesDirectoryExist x)
```

but it doesn't print anything however the following code works fine:

```hs
import System.Directory
main = getCurrentDirectory >>= \x -> doesFileExist x >>= print >> doesDirectoryExist x >>= print
```

any reasons for why the 1st code doesn't print anything ?

Comment: In the first item you use a functor mapping, you thus create for `print <$> doesFileExist x` an `IO (IO ())`, not an `IO ()`.

Answer (score 5):

If you fmap `print` over an IO action, you don't get an `IO` action that performs this printing. You just get an IO action that performs whatever side-effects the original action had, but instead of yielding the printable value as the result it yields another `IO` action as the result which you could then execute in a separate step:

```
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Time

printCurrentTime :: IO ()
printCurrentTime = do
   tPrinter <- print <$> getCurrentTime
   tPrinter
```

or, without `do` notation,

```
printCurrentTime = print <$> getCurrentTime >>= \tPrinter -> tPrinter
```

In other words,

```
printCurrentTime = print <$> getCurrentTime >>= id
```

By the monad laws, `f <$> a >>= b` is the same as `a >>= b . f`, i.e.

```
printCurrentTime = getCurrentTime >>= id . print
```

which is the same as simply

```
printCurrentTime = getCurrentTime >>= print
```

That could than be written with `do` notation as

```
printCurrentTime = do
   t <- getCurrentTime
   print t
```

Comment: I'm here to evangelize `print =<< getCurrentTime`.

Answer (score 4):

As the comment states, you get an `IO (IO ())`. We can use [`join`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:join) to get rid of the duplicate monad.

```
join (print <$> doesFileExist x)
```

But "`fmap` and then `join`" is literally the definition of `>>=` (`join` and `>>=` can be mutually defined in terms of each other). That's why your `>>=` works.

Answer (score 2):

In the first item you use a functor mapping, you thus create for

```
print <$> doesFileExist x :: IO (IO ())
```

Indeed, [**`doesFileExist :: FilePath -> IO Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/directory-1.3.6.2/docs/System-Directory.html#v:doesFileExist) will return an `IO Bool`. Now what you do is perform a functor mapping, so you will map the `Bool` outcome to an `IO ()`, and thus we now have an `IO (IO ())`. This `IO` function will not print anything, since the `IO ()` is the "result" of the IO calculations, not an action.

You thus should use:

```
doesFileExist x >>= print
```

since this will work on the result of `doesFileExist`, and evaluate to an `IO ()` where it will print the `Bool`ean.